# ASP.NET MVC data annotations helpers returns unlimited validation messages on client side validation triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have been searching over Stackoverflow without finding an answer to my issue.
I have an ASP.NET MVC application with view backup by viewmodel with data annotations.
The client-side validations works like a charm when submitting the page.

However, before submitting the page, I sent some AJAX requests to return some dynamic data.
I was looking for a way to validate a small set of input (needed as parameters to the Ajax call).
It seems I found the right javascript command by using the validate() from jquery validate to fire the validation message and display the error message if not valid.
However, I noticed that 2 error messages are displayed:

- span tag with a class 'field-validation-error' coming from the ValidationMessageFor helper set up by ASP.NET
- label tag with a class 'error' that seems to come from the EditorFor helper set up by ASP.NET

And the strange thing is that if I validate again using the validate() method, the span tag remains still, while an additonal label with class 'error' get append after the first label tag (and reapeat as much as I manually validate again).

I was thinking to remove the label tags every time I have to manually validate, but I'm very confused of where does the issue comes from and wonder if there is not a ASP.NET way to solve this issue (like set up a parameter that disallow the addition of label tag while keeping the span error message).

```
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyProperty) 
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyProperty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyProperty)
    </div>
</div>
```

And in my script

```
<script>
     $('form').validate().element('#MyProperty');
</script>
```

Thank for your help